# Creative, recursively enumerable

Tags: logic

I'm trying to show that the set $K$ is creative. $K$ has to do something with $\phi_x$ and the only thing I can get out of creative is if there is a total recursive $f$ s.t. $f(e)$ is an element of $A$ iff $f(e)$ is an element of $W_e$.

Can someone also explain recursive enumerable vs. creativity? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To show $K$ is creative: let $f(e)=e$ be the function.

Not every r.e. set is creative, a counterxample is the [simple set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_set).

It's known that a r.e. set is creative iff it's m-complete iff it's 1-complete. More about it refers to Robert I. Soare *Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees*, Chapter 2.

Comment: Can you please explain why we select f(e) = e to be the functino

Comment: $K=\{x:x\in W_{x}\}$, so $e\in K\leftrightarrow e\in W_{e}$, so we choose $f(e)=e$.

Comment: How does this example show that K is creative? Is it by the s-m-n theorem? I'm trying to better understand this definition. thanks

Comment: Your definition of creative set is there is a total recursive f s.t. f(e) is an element of A iff f(e) is an element of We, so f(e)=e satisfies the definition.